# C++ forward declare class constructor with initialization list

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to separate my classes into header and implementation files:

This works:

header.hpp

```cpp
class MyBaseClass {
    public:
        MyBaseClass(int arg1, int arg2);
};

class MyDerivedClass {
    public:
        MyDerivedClass(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3);
};
```

implementation.cpp

```cpp
MyBaseClass::MyBaseClass(int arg1, int arg2) {
    // do something
}

MyDerivedClass::MyDerivedClass(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
   // do something
}
```

However, I want to make use of inheritance, but this doesn't work:

header.hpp

```cpp
class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass {
    public:
        MyDerivedClass(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) : MyBaseClass(int arg1, int arg2);
};
```

VSCode says `expected '{' or ','`, which I tried and concluded it wanted something like this:

header.hpp

```cpp
class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass {
    public:
        MyDerivedClass(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) : MyBaseClass(int arg1, int arg2) {
            // implementation here
        }
};
```

Am I missing something here, or is the separation I want just not how C++ works? It looks like the obvious way to "extend" the constructor call to the parent, similar to how Java has `super();`.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `MyDerivedClass` you want to call the `MyBaseClass` constructor, not declare it, so just pass the arguments down, don't try to declare them. So remove the `int` before `arg1` and `arg2`.

```
class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass {
    public:
        MyDerivedClass(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) : MyBaseClass(arg1, arg2) {
            // implementation here
        }
};
```

If you want to move the `MyDerivedClass` constructor to a cpp file, then put this into the header:

```
class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass {
    public:
        MyDerivedClass(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3);
};
```

and this into the cpp file:

```
MyDerivedClass::MyDerivedClass(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
    : MyBaseClass(arg1, arg2)
{
}
```

Comment: What if I want to separate the declaration and definition, like the base class? VSCode still tells me `MyDerivedClass(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) : MyBaseClass(arg1, arg2);` is bad.

Comment: @404NameNotFound The semicolon at the end is wrong, you have to end it with `{}` (empty ctor body) at least. If you want to declare constructor and define it later, *only* include the member init list at definition

Comment: This is the definition. The declaration looks like `MyDerivedClass(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3);`.

Comment: @404NameNotFound Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Ah, I see... Thanks for letting me know... I'm learning as I go, and I don't have such a structured reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your inherited class declaration shall not containt the base class constructor.

Instead of :

```cpp
class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass {
    public:
        MyDerivedClass(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) : MyBaseClass(int arg1, int arg2);
};
```

Correct the header file as follows

```cpp
class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass {
    public:
        MyDerivedClass(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3);
};
```